# How to increase Netbeans file path font size?

Tags: netbeans, font-size

I use FullHD 17 inch laptop for coding, I can't see the path of file. I know there is a plugin to show file's path in title bar but I don't want it.
Please take a look at the picture.

[image]

Comment: If you hover the mouse over the tab of any opened file its full path name will be displayed in a popup. For example, "config\index.php" or "web\index.php" in your screen shot. Does that work for your version of NetBeans?

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans [uses 11 as a default](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFontSize) font size for all standard elements such as the main menu or project tree elements. For the element that shows the full path, NetBeans uses a font that smaller on 2 sizes, so it's 11-2=9 and it indeed looks too small on FullHD monitor.
You can increase the default font size for all elements and the size of the FullPath also will be increased. Add:

```
--fontsize 16
```

to netbeans_default_options in netbeans.conf (set you size).

Currently (Netbeans 11.2) you can't increase the font size of FullPath independently. See source [code for it](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/blob/abe93502d5010781955ad22102893d03326c72e2/platform/core.multitabs/src/org/netbeans/core/multitabs/impl/AbstractTabDisplayer.java#L83):

```
Font defaultFont = lblFullPath.getFont();
lblFullPath.setFont( defaultFont.deriveFont( defaultFont.getSize2D()-2 ) );
JPanel controlsPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
```